# Why producer is making more calls to Schema registry instead of using producer cache when using spring-kafka?

Tags: avro, spring-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am using spring-kafka 2.2.8 and we are using confluent schema registry for schema validation since we are publishing avro messages.

Here is how we are setting the schema registry URL in my producer configs.

configs.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryURL);

Now, when I'm sending 10 messages of same type (same schema and same topic), i see 20 calls are being made to the schema registry and each send message is making two calls to SR as shown below

HttpURLConnection[]: getOutputStream
HttpURLConnection[]: getInputStream

Now my questions are:

1. Why is it making two calls to SR for each message?
2. Why the schema information is not being cached on producer side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show your configuration.

I just tested it and only see one call; put a breakpoint in `CachedSchemaRegistry.register()` - I see subsequent calls finding the 'subject` in the cache.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Gary. I debugged and observed that it's hitting the cache but we see two calls in my NewRelic. So, i need to figure out what's happening there..